# Nested object aggregation term with mixed nested/non-nested filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

We have facets showing the number of results that will show when clicking the filters (and combining them). Something like this:

[image: Filters example]

Before we introduced nested objects, the following would do the job:

```
GET /x_v1/_search/
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "FilteredDescriptiveFeatures": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "breadcrumbs.categoryIds": [
                  "category"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "products.sterile": [
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "DescriptiveFeatures": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "products.descriptiveFeatures",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives the result:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "FilteredDescriptiveFeatures": {
      "doc_count": 280,
      "DescriptiveFeatures": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "somekey",
            "doc_count": 42
          },
```

We needed to make `products` a nested object though, and I'm currently trying rewrite the above to work with this change.
My attempt looks like the following. It doesn't give the correct result though, and doesn't seem properly connected to the filter.

```
GET /x_v2/_search/
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "FilteredDescriptiveFeatures": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "breadcrumbs.categoryIds": [
                  "category"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "products",
                "query": {
                  "terms": {
                    "products.sterile": [
                      "0"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "products"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "DescriptiveFeatures": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "products.descriptiveFeatures",
                "size": 1000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives the result:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "FilteredDescriptiveFeatures": {
      "doc_count": 280,
      "nested": {
        "doc_count": 1437,
        "DescriptiveFeatures": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "somekey",
              "doc_count": 164
            },
```

I've also tried to put the nested definition higher up to contain both the filter and aggs, but then the filter term breadcrumbs.categoryId, which is not in the nested object, won't work.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
And how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `FilteredDescriptiveFeatures` step, you return all documents that have one product with `sterile = 0`

But after in the `nested step` you dont specify again this filter. So all nested products are return in this step, thus you make your terms aggregations on all products, not only products with `sterile = 0`

You should move your sterile filter in the nested step. And like Richa points out, you need to use a [reverse_nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) aggregation in the final step to count elasticsearch document and not nested products sub-documents.

Could you try this query ?

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "filteredCategory": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "breadcrumbs.categoryIds": [
                        "category"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "nestedProducts": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "products"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "filteredByProductsAttributes": {
                            "filter": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "products.sterile": [
                                        "0"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "DescriptiveFeatures": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "products.descriptiveFeatures",
                                        "size": 1000
                                    },
                                    "aggs": {
                                        "productCount": {
                                            "reverse_nested": {}
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I under stand from the description is that you want to filter your results on the basis of some Nested and Non Nested Fields and then apply aggregations on the Nested Field. I created a sample Index and data with some Nested and Non Nested Fields and created a query

**Mapping**

```
    PUT stack-557722203
    {
      "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
          "properties": {
            "category": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "user": {
              "type": "nested",       // NESTED FIELD
              "properties": {
                "fName": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "lName": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "type": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Sample Data**

```
    POST _bulk
    {"index":{"_index":"stack-557722203","_id":"1","_type":"_doc"}}
    {"category":"X","user":[{"fName":"A","lName":"B","type":"X"},{"fName":"A","lName":"C","type":"X"},{"fName":"P","lName":"B","type":"Y"}]}
    {"index":{"_index":"stack-557722203","_id":"2","_type":"_doc"}}
    {"category":"X","user":[{"fName":"P","lName":"C","type":"Z"}]}
    {"index":{"_index":"stack-557722203","_id":"3","_type":"_doc"}}
    {"category":"X","user":[{"fName":"A","lName":"C","type":"Y"}]}
    {"index":{"_index":"stack-557722203","_id":"4","_type":"_doc"}}
    {"category":"Y","user":[{"fName":"A","lName":"C","type":"Y"}]}
```

**Query**

```
GET stack-557722203/_search
{
   "size": 0, 
   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "user.fName.keyword": {
                  "value": "A"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "category.keyword": {
              "value": "X"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  "aggs": {
    "group BylName": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "user"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group By lName": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "user.lName.keyword",
           "size": 10
         },
         "aggs": {
           "reverse Nested": {
             "reverse_nested": {}    // NOTE THIS
           }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "took": 18,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group BylName": {
      "doc_count": 4,
      "group By lName": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "B",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "reverse Nested": {
              "doc_count": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "C",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "reverse Nested": {
              "doc_count": 2
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As per the discrepancy in data where you are getting, more documents  in `doc_count` when you changed the mapping to `Nested` is because of the way `Nested` and `Object(NonNested)`  documents are stored. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) to understand how are they internally stored. In order to connect them back to the root Document , you can use [Reverse Nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) aggregation and then you will have the same result.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I think the problem is not only that it does not use the reverse nested for accurate document count. It is also that the filter sterile = 0 is misplaced. It should be used in a filtered aggregation under the nested aggregation.

Comment: @PierreMallet  I think that won't be possible cause if you have nested aggregation on top, you won't be able to use non-nested fields inside that. That's why I would go for Nested query above aggregation, this way you also get the advantage that you will only get the filtered documents and then aggregation would apply only on that. Please correct me if there is some confusion

Comment: if you dont add a filter in the nested aggregation the aggregations will be applied on all nested document of the main document. @Richa can you check my answer below, I have no time to check it but it should work. You can have multiple step of filtering, one for each level of nesting. And it the end the reverse_nested for document count as you highlighted

Comment: Unfortunally this doesn't give the correct result (the answer by Pierre Mallet does), but thanks for the pointers and especially for introducing me to the reverse nested aggregation.